# Docusign: How can we pass values from Template to Recipient Custom Field in Destination URL

Tags: docusignapi

I tried giving a document custom field name in Recipient field name of the Destination URL for Decline/Session Timeout Action, but the value is not getting passed from the document to redirect URL..
Instead the page is redirected to the url as
https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?testId=[[RecipientCustomField1]]

No value is being passed from docusign template form to the field RecipientCustomField1. I have added RecipientCustomField1 as a document custom field and have hardcoded some numbers, but the numbers are not being passed to the redirect destination urls.

Comment: This seems really specialized even for SO, did you ask Docusign support or on docusign forum(s)? What was the result?

Comment: Using envelope custom fields helped address the issue, but template custom fields cannot be passed to the destination urls.